# array.map is not a function reactJS

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks

Whenever I'm trying to use my useDispatch() function from my reducer I'm getting error inside of my component again.

Here is my reducer with which I'm getting all Items from DB and displaying it on the page.

```
export const getPost = (posts : any ) => {


 return {
        type : actionTypes.GET_POSTS,
        posts
    }
}
```

Here is my useEffect in component :

```
    useEffect(() => {
    axios
        .get('http://localhost:4000/getPost')
        .then((res) => {
            // dispatch(actions.getPost({posts : res.data}))
            console.log('--------res', res.data);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log('--------err', err);

        })
})
```

Error is popping up on my `map` method here :

```
 <div id="posts">
            <ul>
                {posts.map((items : any) => {
                    return <li key={uuidv4()} onClick={() => history.push('/postsOnPage')}>{items.title}</li>
                })}
            </ul>
        </div>
```

The error itself is saying: `posts.map is not a function`
And this is that posts : `let posts : any = useSelector((state : any)  => state.posts);`

Any suggestions, please?

Comment: What is the output of `console.log('--------res', res.data)`?

Comment: array of objects

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```js
<div id="posts">
  <ul>
    {Array.isArray(posts) && posts.map((items : any) => {
      return (
        <li
          key={uuidv4()}
          onClick={() => history.push('/postsOnPage')}
         >
           {items.title}
         </li>
      )
     })}
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Error is gone but it is not rendering anything now

Comment: That's because `Array.isArray(posts) === false`. Update the state in your component accordingly. Something like `posts = res.data`

Answer (score 1):

It's probably because `posts` has non-array value (`undefined`, `null` etc.) while API hasn't fetched the data.

You can prevent the error by either checking the value of `posts` first and then running the map or setting the initial value of `posts` as an empty array.

```
<div id="posts">
        <ul>
         {/*Only run the map when posts exists and has the length > 0*/}
            {posts && posts.length > 0 && posts.map((items : any) => {
                return <li key={uuidv4()} onClick={() => history.push('/postsOnPage')}>{items.title}</li>
            })}
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: `console.log(posts)` in the render and see what it has

Comment: it returns objects